# PNG to GeoJSON (or similiar format)

Tags: java, png, geojson, gdal

I have PNG files wich have yellow, orange and red polygons on a white background . I would like to extract the polygons to GeoJSON. 
I already did some research and found out that I can maybe use [gdal_polygonize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) to extract the polygons and than use [drv_geojson](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html) to make it to GeoJSON (both are part of Gdal)

Here are my problems/questions: 
1) What is the best way to call these scripts from java?
2) What are the necessary arguments?
3) Is there a better way you know? Maybe a Java library which does all this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use GDAL. Start by going through [the Java documentation for GDAL](http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/gdal.html), such as `Polygonize()` and [OGR](http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/ogr/ogr.html) for the layer, feature and geometry classes. Use [`ExportToJson()`](http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/ogr/Geometry.html#ExportToJson()) to get the GeoJSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I try it with OSGeo4W for now. I will try your suggestion if I encounter major problems with the other approach.